# How to get a new villager

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I was going to get a saddle but I found that all my villagers were gone how do I get more. I am on a survival world so I cannot spawn them in using spawn eggs.

Comment: Saddles are in underground dungeon chest afaik

Answer (score 1):

You can look for zombie villagers near your village and use splash potion of weakness on them and give them a golden apple afterwards, after waiting a while the zombie villager will be cured and be a normal villager.

Just make sure when you do this that you protect them from the sun while you're waiting for them to be cured otherwise they just die and its a waste of resources.

Comment: And OP would have to make sure the correct workstation is nearby for the Leatherworker job to load into the AI.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe build a base near another village and make a minecart track to your base and buy it. Then you can make a house that lets the villagers go outside so they can have babies and you can get more villagers.

Answer (score 0):

To make more villagers from existing villagers, you would make sure you have a bed for the new villager to sleep in, and feed them bread, carrots or most other types of food made from farms. You would have to find another village and transfer them to the old one, as there is no way to make villagers out of thin air.

Comment: The OP said all of their villagers were "gone", so this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Host on lan and at the lan settings turn on cheats. Then `/gamemode creative` and you can spawn them again!!!

Comment: They are in survival mode. If they wanted to do creative mode, they could just change the world settings (which deactivates achievements).